# How do you get a ScrollPane that is placed in the center of a BorderPane to work?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a program where i have a rootLayout made from a BorderPane. When i press a button in this rootLayout i place a new fxml view into the center of the the borderPane using .setCenter(). The view i am placing into the borderPane consists of an AnchorPane that has a scrollPane as it's child element and when i run this view by itself the scrolling works. However after placing the view into the borderPane it stops working. The area in the scrollPane doesnt move at all when i scroll down or up. I am guessing this has to do with the size that is given in the borderPane but the whole point of having the scrollPane is so that i can show all of the information in 1/3 of the space.

Any tips or Ideas on how to make this work in either javafx, fxml or scenebuilder?

Comment: Do you need the `AnchorPane`? It works fine if you just set the `ScrollPane` directly as the center of the `BorderPane` without wrapping it in an `AnchorPane` first.

Answer (score 0):

Can't make comments yet ... correct me if I'm wrong but don't you have to use the AnchorPane as the child of the ScrollPane? I always have my TextAres as child of the ScrollPanes!